# Isn't funding of TOR a suspicious?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity

I have read on this stack that TOR is funded in major by USA government.

Same government which we may read and watch incredibly untrustful operation about. Is that reliable source of funding.

Is there any proof that the government or its instruments are not asking the reward for donation ? In case of look into some informations that may blame anonimity ?

Anyone have been thinking about such a topic and made reliable discussion or text about ? If yes please let me know.

EDIT:
Why someone have wrote on wikipedia regarding the bitcoin's page such a sentance "Since most darknet markets run through Tor, they can be found with relative ease on public domains.".
This is written in paragraph 3.4 on this site: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptocurrency
I am tired, maybe I understood wrongly this, but I believed that the only one way to detect someone's real identity behing TOR is traffic analysis. And this is not so easy. Please someone may explain me this shortly or let me read something on that issue ?

Comment: It's open source and the network itself is run by volunteers, the directory authorities are run by a set of distinct individuals who are not beholden to the Tor Project or their funders. The Tor Project go to great lenths to reduce the required trust in them. They're also making efforts to increase their funding from other sources aswell. Funders may be questionable but it's possible to hold the resulting code and network to account.

Comment: That is great answer. Thank you.
Just the last sentance is not clear for me. May you rewrite in other words what had you mean ? "it's possible to hold the resulting code and network to account. " Do you mean that you may review the programming code of TOR browser ?

Comment: Yes. It's available and build reproducibly so you can review the code, review the build process and ensure that the reviewed code builds to the distributed binary: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorBrowser/Hacking#BuildingOfficialTorBrowserReleaseBinaries

Comment: The cited wikipedia article intends to say that *if* you are running a marketplace over Tor, it is possible to advertise it's address and for people to easily find it and the things being sold on it *not* that you can discover the location of the market. Infact the very sentence you cite ends *"...all without incriminating any form of user."* and the paragraph ends *"However, dealers and suppliers are able to stay one step ahead of law enforcement, who cannot keep up with the rapidly expanding and anonymous marketplaces of dark markets."*.

Comment: The paragraph in questions states the opposit of the meanig that you have somehow drawn from it but I consider the statements made...overly simplistic.

Comment: Really thank you for the answer. 
It makes the situation clear for me right now.